# Function with type 'T -> Async<'T> like C#'s Task.FromResult

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I'm playing around asynchronous programming and was wondering if there's a function that exists that can take a value of type `'T` and transform it to an `Async<'T>`, similar to C#'s `Task.FromResult` that can take a value of type `TResult` and transform it to a `Task<TResult>` that can then be awaited.

If such a function does not exist in F#, is it possible to create it? I can kind of emulate this by using Async.AwaitTask and Task.FromResult, but can I do this by only using Async?

Essentially, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
let asyncValue = toAsync 3 // toAsync: 'T -> Async<'T>

let foo = async{      
  let! value = asyncValue
}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question to fix the generic types: the apostrophe in F# generic types goes before the letters, not after. E.g., it's `'T`, not `T'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

...or just `async.Return`

```
let toAsync = async.Return
let toAsync` x = async.Return x
```

moreover there is async.Bind (in tupled form)

```
let asyncBind 
    (asyncValue: Async<'a>) 
    (asyncFun: 'a -> Async<'b>) : Async<'b> = 
    async.Bind(asyncValue, asyncFun)
```

you could use them to make pretty complicated async computation without builder [gist link](https://gist.github.com/Szer/60c9c88bec822463bd4af86371f2663b)

```
let inline (>>-) x f = async.Bind(x, f >> async.Return)

let requestMasterAsync limit urls =
    let results = Array.zeroCreate (List.length urls)
    let chunks =
        urls
        |> Seq.chunkBySize limit
        |> Seq.indexed
    async.For (chunks, fun (i, chunk) -> 
        chunk 
        |>  Seq.map asyncMockup 
        |>  Async.Parallel
        >>- Seq.iteri (fun j r -> results.[i*limit+j]<-r))
    >>- fun _ -> results
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `return` within your `async` expression:

```
let toAsync x = async { return x }
```

Comment: Oh, that's it? It's so simple I'm almost ashamed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ghi02 if you liked the answer, please accept it by clicking the pale checkmark to the left.